# Upgrading plugin from 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I am trying to upgrade a project (a set of plugins) from 1.6 to 1.7.
So I changed in `MANIFEST.MF` from 
`Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6` to
`Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7` However, after that upgrade, if I try to export the plugin as a plugin fragment, I got this Eclipse error:

```
Processing inclusion from feature org.eclipse.pde.container.feature: Bundle myplugin_1.0.0 failed to resolve.:
    Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
    Host plug-in JavaSE_0.0.0 has not been found.
```

Edit:

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Auth Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: __NAME__;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Vendor: AVendor
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Export-Package: __A_PACKAGE_NAME__
```

If I change the Target-Platform to `Running platform`, the error disappears (but oviously, I cannot switch the target platform for the whole project). So I suspect the target platform is wrong in some way...

EDIT:

If I remove the line

```
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
```

the export is successful.

Comment: Please show the complete manifest.

Comment: The export and import packages are probably the source of this error. One of those packages might be gone from Java System bundle.

Comment: +1 I had the same problem with an RCP application which I upgraded to Java 8. Removing the 'Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment' entry from the bundle manifest helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh, the project used eclipse 3.5.1, which should be run on 1.6, not on 1.7. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above:

> I had the same problem with an RCP application which I upgraded to Java 8. Removing the 'Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment' entry from the bundle manifest helped.

Comment: I have the same problem with Jdk 10 and removing the line did not work

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using Eclipse Mars 4.5.0 (Build id: 20150621-1200) and Java 8.

MANIFEST.MF

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
...
**Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8**
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"

I did not remove the line "Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8", i changed it to "Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7" and everything works fine.